# Get value of a field from a foreigKey in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two classes in my Database in Django

```
class Test(models.Model):
    sequenzaTest = models.ForeignKey("SequenzaMovimento", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class SequenzaMovimento(models.Model):
    nomeSequenza = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    serieDiMovimenti = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default="")
```

Now, every `Test` object created can be associated with just one `SequenzaMovimento` object. Different `Test` objects can have the same `SequenzaMovimento`

Now, I know the primary key of my Test. How do I find the `serieDiMovimenti` inside the `SequenzaMovimento` object which is linked to the `Test` object?

I can get the `sequenzaTest` from the `Test` object with

```
testo_sequenza = Test.objects.get(pk=idObj)
testo_sequenza.sequenzaTest
```

but I can't find to understand how access serieDiMovimenti

Comment: Are you try `foo = testo_sequenza.sequenzaTest.serieDiMovimenti`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
try:
    testo_sequenza = Test.objects.get(pk=idObj)
except Test.DoesNotExist:
    # do here what you need the program to do if not found. maybe a return if function or a continue/break if you're in a loop
    print("Testo Sequenza not found")
sequenza_test = testo_sequenza.sequenzaTest
serie_di_movimenti = sequenza_test.serieDiMovimenti
```

Also you should check

```
serieDiMovimenti = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default="")
```

Because if you want it to be "optional field" then it would be `blank=True`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
testo_sequenza = Test.objects.get(pk=idObj)
testo_sequenza.sequenzaTest.serieDiMovimenti
```